# MYSQL selecting from table 1 with conditions from 2nd table

Tags: mysql

my first table, called `emp` is an employees table, with information such as names, phone numbers, town, etc.

My second table, called `loc` a table of cities and the country’s they are in. - in this list there are LESS cities than there are in the 1st table. (the purpose of the cities list is irrelevant atm)

i want to pull a list (select from) of name and phone number which for that i used `select Name,Number from Full_list` and it worked - BUT i only want it to show the employees that live in cities that are in the "cities" column in my 'loc' tablet. i also want it to display the country if possible.

i tired stuff like

```
select Name,Number from Full_list where City from Cities
```

but it didnt work.

Edit: wanted to add the exact keys to make this simpler

Table 1:

```
EmpList
name    number
```

Table 2:

```
Cities
city   country
```

this is what i wanted "checked" against the `city` column in tablet 1, if there is a match, i want it to appear.

column 2 `country` i also want that to appear if possible.

TY

Comment: have yo any foreign key in LOC table for emp?

Comment: Can you provide the structure of both tables?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT F.Name, F.Number 
FROM EmpList as E
INNER JOIN Cities as C ON (C.PRIMARY_KEY = E.FOREIGN_KEY)
WHERE C.cities LIKE '%YOUR CITY%';
```

Change the keys to your table keys...

Comment: First of all ty for the quick answer. Not sure what keys replace the .cityId after the loc. and F., also not sure what replaces the cityName and the '%YOUR CITY%'

Comment: @Giladiald This keys i've mentioned is your primary key from loc table, and foreign key from  Full_list table, making the relation between these two tables. How you making the relation between these two tables?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have any relationship between these two tables, you have to join with the city name.

Try this:

```
SELECT Emp.Name,LOC.city,LOC,country
FROM Employee Emp INNER JOIN
     LOC on Emp.city=LOC.city
WHERE LOC.City LIKE '%London%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two SELECT statements in one QUERY like that :

```
SELECT E.Name, E.Number
FROM Emplist as E
WHERE E.CityName = (SELECT C.CityName FROM Cities as C WHERE C.CityName LIKE '%YourName%')
```

But the best to use is the INNER JOIN :

```
SELECT E.Name, E.Number 
FROM EmpList as E
INNER JOIN Cities as C ON (C.CityName = E.CityName )
WHERE C.CityName LIKE '%YOUR CITY%';
```